# Is opponenture an English word?

Tags: single-word-requests, is-it-a-word

I hear the word "Opponenture" from Czech speakers a lot. I can understand its meaning from its root, but I can't find it in any dictionary or in google. Is it a valid English word? If not, what should be used instead?

For example, if you heard this sentence would it make sense to you? If not, how would you say it?

> I will discuss the proposal with the team and everyone will try to make an opponenture.

Comment: It seems Latin. Does the word exist in Czech?

Comment: Yes, it's oponentura.

Comment: Then I think that's your 'answer': since the word grammatically foreign and similar to many English nouns many might assume it is English, while it's not. (Not a single result on [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=opponenture&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) either.)

Comment: Hello, Bizhan. Could you just say which dictionaries you've tried, please, to avoid others repeating those searches unnecessarily?

Comment: Google Translate gives _opponency_ as the English version. As a pretty well-read person. I had to look that up. Apart from the general 'opposition', apparently it means the act of stating an argument in a formal academic disputation. I don't know if that sense fits the OP's example sentence.

Comment: Can you give more details on the context and meaning. Are people objecting to the proposal, or are they trying to get more information, or is there a formal process of challenging where people must come up with as many objections as possible to test the proposal? Is it just people asking questions after a presentation? This seems like there might be a word in specific contexts (e.g. debating/forensics, higher education, law, or some project management schemata) but not a general English word.

Comment: Since *opponenture* is not an English word, and *opponency* is "archaic", perhaps say: "I will discuss the proposal with the team and everyone will try to make a refutation".

Comment: Where does that spelling come from? You heard the word, right? oponenture (one p) comes out as opponent in Google Translate.

Comment: @StuartF it's in formal speech and it has a general context, as in a technical discussion.

Comment: @Lambie I guessed the spelling (I don't trust the spelling of my colleagues no offense to them!) I looked it up in a Czech dictionary and it was written as oponentura. with one `p` and an `a` at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word does not exist in English.

You likely mean

> I will discuss the proposal with the team so anyone can raise objections.

*Objections* in this context are defined as

> a: a reason or argument presented in opposition 
> b: a feeling or expression of disapproval

[MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/objection)